# Compilation of Qualities of Rama and Ravana

Tags: ramayana, rama, bhagavata-purana, ravana

I want, Compilation of qualities of Rama and Ravana

collected from verses of various scriptures.

citing the particular verse-and writing the Sanskrit word for that quality

Comment: It is a broad question, I think you can narrow it down to scripture like Valmiki Ramayana at least.

Comment: Also the question can't be limited to sanskrit also, as there are many other ramayan esp. The great epic ramcharitmanas

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a forum for homework questions.

Answer (score 2):

Some notable verses from Valmiki Ramayan that exalts the qualities of Shri Rama  :- see [link](https://www.valmiki.iitk.ac.in/sloka?field_kanda_tid=1&language=ro&field_sarga_value=1)

Sage Valmiki queries about a single perfect individual bestowed with all good qualities enumerated by him -- Sage Narada, knower of past, present and future, identifies such a man -- describes virtues, qualities of Sri Rama

Following Verses that personifies Lord Rama's qualities (16 kalyana gunas)

> **konvasmin saamprataM loke guNavaankashgcha viiryavaan |dharmajJNashcha kRitajJNashcha satyavaakyo dRiDhavrataH
>
> cāritrēṇa ca kō yuktassarvabhūtēṣu kō hita: .
> vidvānka: kassamarthaśca kaścaikapriyadarśana:
>
> ētadicchāmyahaṅ śrōtuṅ paraṅ kautūhalaṅ hi mē .
> maharṣē tvaṅ samarthō.si jñātumēvaṅvidhaṅ naram**
> Who now in this world, can be embellished by superlatives pertaining to great character(sousheelyam) ,valour, noble virtues, gratitude conscious, true to  word, Firm in resolve, propriety of great order, benign to all beings, irrefutable scholar with adorable ability ,charismatic, always with a pleasant countenance,courageous ,one who has won over anger , jealousy and greed ,all intelligent ,and by whom, even the Gods are afraid to combat with in any battlefield."
> (Valmiki Ramayan 1.1.2,1.1.3,1.1.4,)

**Ramo Vigrahavaan Dharmaha**

see [link](https://www.valmiki.iitk.ac.in/sloka?field_kanda_tid=3&language=dv&field_sarga_value=37)

Maricha- Ravana Conversation-

Maricha said

> **Raamo vigrahavaan dharmaH saadhuH satya paraakramaH |
> raajaa sarvasya lokasya devaanaam iva vaasavaH || AranyaKhanda 37.13**
> Rama is dharma incarnate. He is pious. His strength is truth. He is king of all the worlds like Indra to the gods.(Valmiki Ramayan 3.37.13)

**Qualities of Ravana**

Maricha said

> अपि त्वामीश्वरं प्राप्य कामवृत्तं निरङ्कुशम्।
> न विनश्येत्पुरी लङ्का त्वया सह सराक्षसा।
> I hope the city of Lanka along with the (entire) race of demons will not be destroyed, with a dictator like you who is a slave to sensual pleasure.(Valmiki Ramayana 3.37.6)

> त्वद्विधः कामवृत्तो हि दुश्शीलः पापमन्त्रितः।
> आत्मानं स्वजनं राष्ट्रं स राजा हन्ति दुर्मतिः
> A king who is a slave to passion, who is of bad conduct, of wicked thoughts, advised in evil ways destroys himself, his kith and kin and the entire kingdom.(Valmiki Ramayan 3.37.7)

> **You are fickleminded**. You have employed no spy ( who could have told you the truth about Rama's character). Rama is very brave and virtuous comparable to Indra and Varuna. Surely you are not able to know what Rama is(Valmiki Ramayana 3.37.3)

PS-There could be more instances , I've highlighted just  few